# When using VS2022 (v17.0.1.0), the complier can not recognize "string", and sends me an error. When I replace the string by const char*, it works

Tags: c++

I have tried searching on Google, only to find nothing.

And it seems the manual also doesn't work.

Here is my code:

account.h

```
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"

class SavingsAccount
{
public:
    void show();   
    void deposit(Date now_date, double money, string ways);     
    void withdraw(Date now_date, double money, const char* ways);   
    void settle(Date new_date);   
    SavingsAccount(Date date_new, const char* id_new, double rate_new);
    void accountshow();
    static double getTotal();  
    static SavingsAccount* point; 
    static int sum_account;  
    static double sum_money;
private:
    const char* id;
    double balance = 0;
    double rate = 0;
    int lastDate = 0;
    Date date;
    double interest = 0;
};
```

account.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "account.h"
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

double SavingsAccount::sum_money = 0;

void SavingsAccount::deposit(Date now_date, double money, string ways)   //<--- here is the problem
{
    interest += balance * (now_date - date) * rate / 366;
    date = now_date;
    date.show();
    cout << "\t#" << id << "\t" << money << "\t" << money + balance << "\t"<<ways << endl;
    balance += money;
    sum_money += money;
}

void SavingsAccount::withdraw(Date now_date, double money, const char* ways)   //取款
{
    interest += balance * (now_date - date) * rate / 366;
    date = now_date;
    date.show();
    cout << "\t#" << id << "\t-" << money << "\t" << balance - money << "\t" << ways << endl;
    balance -= money;
    sum_money -= money;
}

void SavingsAccount::settle(Date new_date)     //结算利息
{
    interest += balance * (new_date - date) * rate / 366;
    interest = (int(interest * 100 + 0.5)) / 100.0;
    sum_money += interest;
    date = new_date;
    date.show();
    cout << "\t#" << id << "\t" << interest << "\t" << interest + balance << " interest"<<endl;
    balance += interest;
    interest = 0;
}

void SavingsAccount::accountshow()
{
    this->date.show();
    cout << "\t" << "#" << id << " created" << endl;
}

void SavingsAccount::show()
{
    cout << id << "\tBalance: " << balance;
}

SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(Date date_new, const char* id_new, double rate_new) : id(id_new)
{
    date = date_new;
    rate = rate_new;
    //sum_account++;
    balance = 0;
    interest = 0;
    accountshow();
}

double SavingsAccount::getTotal()
{
    return sum_money;
}
```

bank.cpp:

```
#include "account.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Date date(2008, 11, 1);
    SavingsAccount accounts[] = {
        SavingsAccount(date, "S3755217", 0.015),
        SavingsAccount(date, "02342342", 0.015)
    };

    const int n = sizeof(accounts) / sizeof(SavingsAccount); 
    string works = "salary";
    accounts[0].deposit(Date(2008, 11, 5), 5000, works);
    accounts[1].deposit(Date(2008, 11, 25), 10000, "sell stock 0323");
    accounts[0].deposit(Date(2008, 12, 5), 5500, "salary");
    accounts[1].withdraw(Date(2008, 12, 20), 4000, "buy a laptop");
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        accounts[i].settle(Date(2009, 1, 1));
        accounts[i].show();
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Total: " << SavingsAccount::getTotal() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Because of the limited length for this, I did not show the `Date.h` and `Date.cpp`, and there is nothing wrong with it. But I will show it to you if you need.

Here is the problem, and I translate the error the VS tells me into English:

[image]

VS also says:

> 'void SavingsAccount::deposit(Date,double,std::string)' there is no overloading member function declared in `SavingsAccount`

But when I replace the `string` by `const char*`, just like what I write in the `withdraw()` function, it works without any problem.

[image: here is the result]

So, could you please tell me how can I use `string` to finish this problem? Because `const char*` is so uncomfortable to be used.

Comment: What problem are you looking for help with? The inability to use `std::string`? If so, reduce the code example to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem (make a [mre]). This will allow us to reproduce the compiler diagnostics in whatever language is supported by our tools.

Comment: Until the first `using namespace std;` is read by the compiler, `string` is treated as an unknown type by the compiler, since it doesn't know  you want to refer to the type from namespace `std`. This occurs both for `main.cpp` and `account.cpp` (assuming `Date.h` doesn't contain `using namespace std;`). Just use `std::string` instead of `string`, at least in the header (you don't make assumptions whether the user wants to everything in `std` to be available via the global namespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `account.h`, you have `#include <string>`, but you do not have `using namespace std;` ([and rightly so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/)), so the compiler doesn't know what `string` is.  You have to use `std::string` instead, eg:

```
void deposit(Date now_date, double money, std::string ways);
```

Or, use `using std::string`, at least (not recommended in a header, though):

```
using std::string;
...
void deposit(Date now_date, double money, string ways);
```

In `account.cpp` and `bank.cpp`, you have `using namespace std;` after `#include <string>`, so the compiler can work out what `string` is without needing you to  qualify it with `std::`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.It works well.This is my first time to try to use multiple files to sovle a problem.The question seems a little stupid.